# How to keep playing YouTubePlayer in Android

Tags: android, youtube

Now I'm creating an Android application witch use YouTube api to play Video.
But the player stop when I change Activity.
I want to keep Playing like a Music Player even when Activity will change.
I try to solve that by adding Static on YouTubePlayer.(But cannot solve.)

I mean I want to Keep it's playing when the Activity or the Application itself move to Background.

So if you have any ideas, please share with me :)

-----------------Code-----------------

```
public class PlayActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener{
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "My_Dev_Key";
private LinearLayout yPos;
private static YouTubePlayer yt;
private YouTubePlayerView ytp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play);

    yPos = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.youtube_pos);

    try{
        ytp = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
        ytp.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }catch(Exception e){
        finish();
    }

    yPos.addView(ytp);
}

@Override
public void onAdStarted() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLoading() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onVideoEnded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onVideoStarted() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1,
        boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!arg2){
        if(yt == null){
            yt = arg1;
            yt.setPlayerStateChangeListener(this);
            yt.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            yt.loadVideo("u0v5A6cQOhs");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I know what you saying, but I just wanna make a Music Player on YouTube.I know it perform very bad if you use the app as 'pure' Music Player, So I supposes that as a BGM player(So user have nothing to do on smart phone then).

Comment: Decoding a video is a very CPU/GPU intensive work. This will drain battery very fast. Forget it, even with screen disabled this will drain persons akku within hours. Users will hate you, for good.